# ReactJS component not fetching my Heroku hosted API, will fetch other APIs

Tags: reactjs, heroku, fetch

I have a component which calls an API I've deployed with Heroku:

```
import React from 'react';

class ApiCaller extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      load: '',
    };
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    fetch('https://skincierge-data-api-1.herokuapp.com/api/v1/query/?SKIN_TYPE=oily&ANTI_AGEING=True&PRIMARY_CONCERN=wrinkles&BUNDLE_PRICE_LIMIT=350&SECONDARY_CONCERN=spots')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
        this.setState({load: JSON.stringify(data)})
    })
    .catch(console.log)
  }

    render(){
        return(
        <div>
            {this.state.load}
        </div>
    )
    };
}

export default ApiCaller;
```

It returns the response json of the API call inside a `<div>` tag. For some reason, it hangs when I call my API in Heroku, but works when I call everything else (e.g. the [International Space Station API](https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544)).

I've been troubleshooting this for hours and am at a loss; does anybody know how to fetch the data from my API?

Comment: It seems like a backend error. Because request fails as per the status in network tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by `server side.`

> It has been blocked by [CORS](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled#In_ASP.NET) policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'.

So, You have to [Enable CORS](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled#In_ASP.NET) in your API.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is within your backend api. it throws a CORS policy. You should whitelist your front-end domain in your backend.